# finding max sum of matrix rows and columns, these are 2 codes i got 1 is working but the other is not,though the array initialization are the same

Tags: c, arrays

in code 1,the array run time initialization was working fine but in code 2 it isnt         though both the codes are nearly same

#### Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int A[n][n],i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
    }
    int sum=0, newsum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        newsum = 0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {  
            newsum = newsum + A[i][j];
        }
        if(sum < newsum)
        {
            sum = newsum;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Code 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dim,i,j,k,h=0;
    scanf("%d",k);
    int array[k][k];
    int max[2k+2]={0};

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //rows
    h=max[0];
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            max[i]+=array[i][j];

        }
        if(max[i]>=h)
        {
            h=max[i];
        }   
    }
    //columns 
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            max[j+k]+=array[i][j];
        }
        if(max[j+k]>=h)
        {
            h=max[j+k];
        }

    }  
    //diagonal_1
    for(i,j=0;j<k && i<k;j++,i++) 
    {
        max[2k]+=array[i][j];
    }
    for(i=0,j=k-1;j>=0&&i<k;j--,i++) 
    { 
        max[2k+1]+=array[i][j];
    }          
    if(max[2k]>=max[2k+1])
        max[2k]=max[2k]; 
    else
        max[2k]=max[2k+1];

    if(max[2k]>=h)
        printf("%d",max[2k]);
    else
        printf("%d",h);   

    return 0;
}
```

The errors that occurred are:

```
Program: In function 'main':
Program:11:9: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:48:6: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect[-       
Program:50:13: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:54:9: error: fixed-point types not supported for this  target    
Program:56:8: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:56:17: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target    
Program:57:5: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target 
Program:57:13: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:59:5: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target    
Program:59:13: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target 
Program:61:8: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:62:17: error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
Program:11:5: warning: unused variable 'max' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: There are too many errors here. You need to work through each error in turn, starting with the first. If there are any specific errors that you don't understand and haven't found a solution for elsewhere online, then ask about them specifically.

Comment: quite a story in your thread title.

Answer (score 1):

Well , you can't declare an array using a variable like int max[2k+2]={0} , because the size of array must be sure in the compile period .

Comment: And also , initiations like int a[10] = {0} only initialize first element in array .

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
int max[2k+2]={0};
```

You can't use `2k` in C, like in maths, which is not valid. You need to use `2*k`. The same problem in multiple places in your code 2.

And C11, 6.7.9 specifically states that you can't have initializers for VLAs.

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown
>   size or an object type that is not a variable length array type.

So you have to remove the initializer for the variable length array.

2.

Your first scanf() is missing `&`.

Change

```
scanf("%d",k);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&k);
```

3.

```
for(i,j=0;j<k && i<k;j++,i++)
```

Here, the `i` in initialization part doesn't do anything. You probably meant to initialize it with 1.

Comment: `int max[2*k+2]={0};` also does not work, that initializer should be removed.

Comment: Thanks i corrected the 2*k and Removing the initialization fixed the errors,few of my friends suggested to use malloc for this kind of problems Which ones better to use?

Comment: @saratb Variable length arrays are supported since C99 (as an extension in gcc compiler before that). So it's upto you decide based on which version C standard your compiler supports and your needs. Use malloc for large arrays or if VLAs are not available. Large array allocations are somewhat dangerous as there's no ideal way to test if automatic (stack) allocations succeeded.